# Chrome doesn't display text properly

Tags: google-chrome, text

chrome doesn't display texts properly.

I've searched web and tried solution but nothing has been changed.
(#disable-direct-write)

any way to solve this problem?

texts are shown like this ↓

[image: text problem]

※ I launched developer tools to check CSS, then this happened..

Seriously.. what's going on?!

[image: in developer tools]

Comment: I think it is the first parameter of the *text-shadow* CSS property of the element. Does the same happens on Firefox?
I tried to do the same [here on jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j11Lcyb7/)

Comment: This seems to be an encoding problem.
Google suggested a solution [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95290?hl=en).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text-shadow that has been applied on the text might be causing this issue.
Please verify the optimum parameters again.

```
text-shadow: 2px 0px 1px black;
```

[JSFiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/j11Lcyb7/)

Comment: Thanks! changing settings were very useful. actually reboot solved problem :(

Comment: Ooh, alright. Glad your problem has been resolved :) I suspect for some reason chrome 'wrongly' chose its encoding which lead you to that.